# Difficulty with Scatter and Gather pattern with Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have an object like this

```
case class Foo(id: Int, id1: Option[Int], id2: Option[Int])
```

Here id1 and id2 are obtained in two separate lookups. So first I scatter using the broadcast and then I do a gather using a merge and a groupBy.

The code I have written is

```
val source = Source(List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)))
val flow1 = Flow[Foo].map(foo => foo.copy(id1 = Some(Random.nextInt())))
val flow2 = Flow[Foo].map(foo => foo.copy(id2 = Some(Random.nextInt())))
val flow3 = Flow[Foo].groupBy(100, foo => foo.id)
val flow4 = Flow[Foo].reduce{case (foo, fooLookup) =>
     if (fooLookup.id1.isDefined) foo.copy(id1 = fooLookup.id1)
     if (fooLookup.id2.isDefined) foo.copy(id2 = fooLookup.id2)
     else foo
}
val sink = Sink.foreach[Foo](println)
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink) { implicit builder =>
  s =>
     import GraphDSL.Implicits._
     val b = builder.add(Broadcast[Foo](2))
     val m = builder.add(Merge[Foo](2))
     source ~> b
     b ~> flow1 ~> m
     b ~> flow2 ~> m
     m ~> flow3.mergeSubStreams ~> flow4 ~> s.in
     ClosedShape
   })
```

This doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't like the flow3.mergeSubStreams.

My final goal is that the lookup for id1 and id2 happens on two separate branches and I should be able to merge and print the final object which has id, id1 and id2.

Edit:: Another question I have is that since I had split the stream into 2 the reduce function should move forward once it has processed 2 Foos. Right now it seems that the reduce function will wait for the entire stream to end because it doesn't know how many foos it will receive. So is there a way to tell the reducer that once it has received certain number of records it should pass it on to the sink.

Comment: You code contains many compilation errors. Please tidy up the code in a way to reproduce the error.

Comment: but that's exactly my problem that I am not able make the code compile once the stream has been grouped.

Comment: the case class definition for `Foo`, for example, doesn't compile. Also, `mergeSubStreams` combinator would not compile, as its correct call is `mergeSubstreams`.